# DLL only injects if I inject together with it's dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, dll-injection

I was using this source code for learning purpose https://github.com/W1lliam1337/digital-sdk. It was working since last week but then I changed some Visual Studio settings and copy&pasted source to other folder and today it started not working anymore.There it generates some dll files on debug/release folder when I compile project.I was only injecting cheat dll to make it work and it was working but now its not working if I only inject cheat dll and then as you can see I tried to inject all of them together after I click inject button 3 times Its worked. Can someone help me with that ? **Other projects works well**. What did I change and its caused this ? I really have no idea I don't have knowledge on Visual Studio settings too.Please someone help me

Edit : I tried other injectors too still not working  Its more like I messed up with project/Visual Studio settings
VIDEO
https://streamable.com/rvn7bg

Here is how my DllMain and Thread looks like.

```cpp
DWORD WINAPI HackThread(HMODULE hModule)
{
    AllocConsole();
    FILE* f;
    freopen_s(&f, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

//My Stuff bla bla..

while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END) & 1)
    {
        Sleep(20);
    }
    if (f) fclose(f);
    FreeConsole();
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hModule, 0);
    return 0;
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hmodule,
                       DWORD reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID reserved
) {
    if ( reason_for_call != DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH )
        return FALSE;

    /* @xref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-disablethreadlibrarycalls */
    DisableThreadLibraryCalls( hmodule );

    std::thread( instance ).detach( );

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please tell me what setting you changed that caused this error?

Comment: @JamesRisner There is no error messages as you can see in video.

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT I changed some options on these 2 tab but I don't really remember which one. https://prnt.sc/yUjnZguSmuOK https://prnt.sc/r8SZYNm8NfjE and then I changed some project include/library directory.I deleted/changed some library/include macros here https://prnt.sc/TGB0Kz9V2bKH here is how my include/library directories looks. https://prnt.sc/0XXdnzL04xKG https://prnt.sc/cok6k2QN3jI0   Do I miss something ? As I remember I deleted 1 include directory named Windows something like that I just deleted macro.Then tried to add same include macro but maybe not same ?

Comment: In general, libraries or header files are required, and you should not delete or change directories at will. I suggest you try to recover the file or directory you deleted.